# Passing javascript valiables from HTML form to PayPal

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

I've done up a form with an auto calculation script on it but I can't seem to pass on the **amount** value to PayPal.

Is their a way to convert the java variable into a php variable or some other trick?

I've been Googleing for over 2 hrs and my eyes are spinning in their sockets. :)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function $_(IDS) { return document.getElementById(IDS); }
    function setPrice () {
        var A = parseFloat($_('A').value*10.);
        var B = parseFloat($_('B').value*10.);
        var C = parseFloat($_('C').value*10.);
        var D = parseFloat($_('D').value*10.);
        var E = parseFloat($_('E').value*10.);
        var F = parseFloat($_('F').value*10.);
        var G = parseFloat($_('A').value*1.);
        var H = parseFloat($_('B').value*1.);
        var I = parseFloat($_('C').value*1.);
        var J = parseFloat($_('D').value*1.);
        var K = parseFloat($_('E').value*1.);
        var L = parseFloat($_('F').value*1.);

        var kids = (G+H+I+J+K+L);

            if (kids==1){
                var result = (+A+B+C+D+E+F).toFixed(2);
            }
            if (kids==2){
                var result = (+A+B+C+D+E+F-5).toFixed(2);
            }
            if (kids>2){
                var result = (+A+B+C+D+E+F-6).toFixed(2);
            }

            if (kids==1){
                var tax = ((+A+B+C+D+E+F)*1.13).toFixed(2);
            }
            if (kids==2){
                var tax = ((+A+B+C+D+E+F-5)*1.13).toFixed(2);
            }
            if (kids>2){
                var tax = ((+A+B+C+D+E+F-6)*1.13).toFixed(2);
            }

        $_('kids1').value = kids;   
        $_('total1').value = result;    
        $_('amount').value = tax;
    };
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@mysite.com" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="2014/2015 Registration" />
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD" />
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mysite.com/payments/?payment=success" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.mysite.com/payments/?payment=cancelled" />
        <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_paynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />

        <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" id="A" onChange="setPrice()">
        <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" id="B" onChange="setPrice()">
        <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" id="C" onChange="setPrice()">
        <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" id="D" onChange="setPrice()">
        <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" id="E" onChange="setPrice()">
        <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" id="F" onChange="setPrice()">

        <br>

        Order total = $<input type="text" id="total1" readonly /><br>
        With tax total = $<input type="text" id="amount" readonly /><br>
        Total Kids = <input type="text" id="kids1" readonly /><br>

        <br>

        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="PayPal . The safer, easier way to pay online." />
</form>
```

Comment: where is the php code? which variable to pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed to pass the amount and tax values to paypal.No need to use `PHP` . You need to pass `amount` and `tax` variables to paypal.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function $_(IDS) { return document.getElementById(IDS); }
    function setPrice () {
        var A = parseFloat($_('A').value*10.);
        var B = parseFloat($_('B').value*10.);
        var C = parseFloat($_('C').value*10.);
        var D = parseFloat($_('D').value*10.);
        var E = parseFloat($_('E').value*10.);
        var F = parseFloat($_('F').value*10.);
        var G = parseFloat($_('A').value*1.);
        var H = parseFloat($_('B').value*1.);
        var I = parseFloat($_('C').value*1.);
        var J = parseFloat($_('D').value*1.);
        var K = parseFloat($_('E').value*1.);
        var L = parseFloat($_('F').value*1.);

        var kids = (G+H+I+J+K+L);

            if (kids==1){
                var result = (+A+B+C+D+E+F).toFixed(2);
            }
            if (kids==2){
                var result = (+A+B+C+D+E+F-5).toFixed(2);
            }
            if (kids>2){
                var result = (+A+B+C+D+E+F-6).toFixed(2);
            }

            if (kids==1){
                var tax = ((+A+B+C+D+E+F)*1.13).toFixed(2);
            }
            if (kids==2){
                var tax = ((+A+B+C+D+E+F-5)*1.13).toFixed(2);
            }
            if (kids>2){
                var tax = ((+A+B+C+D+E+F-6)*1.13).toFixed(2);
            }

        $_('kids1').value = kids;   
        $_('total1').value = result;    
        $_('amount').value = tax;

        //assign values to paypal buttons
        $_('amt_val').value = result;
        $_('tax_val').value = tax;
    };
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@mysite.com" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="2014/2015 Registration" />
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD" />
        <input type="hidden" id="amt_val" name="amount" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" id="tax_val" name="tax" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mysite.com/payments/?payment=success" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.mysite.com/payments/?payment=cancelled" />
        <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_paynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />

        <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" id="A" onChange="setPrice()">
        <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" id="B" onChange="setPrice()">
        <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" id="C" onChange="setPrice()">
        <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" id="D" onChange="setPrice()">
        <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" id="E" onChange="setPrice()">
        <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="3" id="F" onChange="setPrice()">

        <br>

        Order total = $<input type="text" id="total1" readonly /><br>
        With tax total = $<input type="text" id="amount" readonly /><br>
        Total Kids = <input type="text" id="kids1" readonly /><br>

        <br>

        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="PayPal . The safer, easier way to pay online." />
</form>
```

Try this code to get output like this [image]

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h48De/)

Comment: Thanks! I did pass it at one point but not this way. Just forgot to add that line to my example. Wish I had asked this question about 2/hrs ago and many Google searches. Time for bed.